# Simplified "Razor-Only" website?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a website I want to make using the Razor template engine, however it really only has one simple page with a basic AJAX form in it. Having a full-blown MVC Web Application seems like a massive overkill for this, but I don't want to have to use something like PHP. Can I use Razor in a 'PHP-like' manner (i.e. one or two .cshtml/.vbhtml pages I can make requests to, in a similar function to how you make requests to .php pages)?

This will be hosted on IIS 8, if that'll help.

Comment: Check out http://www.asp.net/web-pages/videos/aspnet-razor-pages and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, it is possible to make a razor only website (without MVC).

Comment: Oh, that easy, huh? I haven't really played around with anything beyond MVC, but this makes sense. Did you mind converting your comment to an answer so I can give you due credit? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use razor with ASP.NET Websites (not web projects).

To do this go to `File` > `New Web Site...` and pick one of the templates that supports razor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Gives more depth, however, you might be able to skip the first step *"Installing the ASP.NET Razor Tools"* if you already have it installed.